# How to click on the checkbox? even aria-hidden is = true?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

It is giving me error of Element is not visible. Below I have mentioned the JavaScript code. I want to click on aMRI.

I am using python selenium:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for = 'aMRI' and @class = 'checkbox-label']//span[@class='checkbox']//input[@id='aMRI']").click()
```

HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <label for="aMRI" class="checkbox-label">
        <span class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="aMRI">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span> MRI
    </label>
    <label for="aCase1" class="checkbox-label">
        <span class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="aCase1">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span> Case1
    </label>
    <label for="aDistibution" class="checkbox-label">
        <span class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="aDistibution">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span> Distibution
    </label>
    <label for="aBandwidth" class="checkbox-label hide">
        <span class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="aBandwidth">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span> Bandwidth
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `aria-hidden="true"` is an attribute of italic node, not `input`... Just try to wait until checkbox becomes visible/clickable

Comment: Please provide URL for better answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the *Check Box* related to the `<label>` with text as **MRI** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='aMRI']").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The element must be display on screen. Try to scroll page and than click

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: Still no improvement.

Answer (score 1):

try this **code** :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "aMRI"))  
element.click()
```